# laplace transform of dirac delta function in matlab

Tags: matlab

My question is about the difference between these two definitions of dirac delta function in Matlab: `dirac(t,1)` and `dirac(t-1)` I tried to apply the laplace transform and inverse laplace transform to these 2 functions and they give me very different results:

```
syms s t
F_s=s+s^2; % definition of the function in s domain
f_t=ilaplace(F_s)

f_t =

dirac(t, 1) + dirac(t, 2)

F_s=laplace(f_t)

F_s =

s^2 + s

F_s=laplace(dirac(t-1)+dirac(t-2)) % but if I use this definition for dirac delta function it gives a very diffrent answer...

F_s =

exp(-s) + exp(-2*s)
```

and my problem is that when i want to plot the function as:

```
t=1:0.1:4; 
f_t1=dirac(t, 1) + dirac(t, 2);
```

> Error using double.dirac Too many input arguments.

It can't plot the function so I used the definition as :

`dirac(t-1)+dirac(t-2)` but it gives a very different answer in Laplace transform... could you please explain the reason to me?

Thank you all

sahar